# cannot read zip file entry

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven

I have a maven project which is giving me **BUILD FAILURE** with the following error when I try to run `mvn install`:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project core: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Users\lawson\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\3.0.5.RELEASE\spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar; cannot read zip file entry
```

I already see all the dependencies under **Maven Dependencies** in my project in Eclipse.
Could someone help me understand why am I getting this error?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a Spring repository location in your pom.xml, if so try to remove it

Comment: @Joey: No, I don't have Spring repository location in my pom. I just have `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2` and other repository for third party specific snapshot jars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to first try to delete the contents of the folder: C:\Users\lawson.m2\repository\org\springframework and afterward redo the mvn clean package of your project. Furthermore i would suggest to update the maven-compiler-plugin version via

```
 <build>
   <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.4</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
 </build>
```

It looks like you have downloaded a jar file which was corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your local repository entry for spring-beans is corrupt in some way.  You may be able to reinstall it with the `mvn install:install-file` goal. See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html.

Comment: Simpler is to delete the folder in the local repository and just retry the build. It's just simpler.

Comment: @khmarbaise, I suspected as much.  But I've never done that myself and I didn't want to suggest something I hadn't tried.

Comment: There were just too many files for which I was getting that error and I ended up deleting my local repository which was 1GB or so. I've been trying to download those jars ever since and maven and eclipse helios have driven me total nuts. I've been having these errors on an off for past few days and I've gone all nuts :(

Comment: I finally seem to have things working alright. It took ages for maven central to  get updated. Thanks.